# Using viewpager by recycling a single fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm creating a viewpager with around 4-5 tabs. All of the tabs will have a listview with different elements. Clearly, all the fragments can simply inflate a single layout file and add in their own stuff to the listview adapter.

Effectively I'll have a bunch of listviews side by side.

My question is, if I can use a single layout file, can I also use a single fragment?

I understand that the viewpager needs different fragments for each tab. But given that I'm simply changing the very-light listview (list item = 1 textview) in each of the tabs, can I somehow recycle the same fragment by using the position of the viewpager (which tab is opened)

Anyways, here's my TitleAdapter:

```
public class TitleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private String titles[] = new String[]{"View1","View2","View3"};
    private Fragment frags[] = new Fragment[titles.length]; 

    public TitleAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        frags[0] = new FragmentView1();
        frags[1] = new FragmentView2();
        frags[2] = new FragmentView3();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position){
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", titles[position]);
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
        return frags[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return frags.length;
    }

}
```

As you can see, right now I've got 3 fragments. But I don't want to head off in the wrong direction if there's a way that offers better performance or even a few kilobyte less app size. The FragmentView's are my fragments for each of the tab, in which I'm inflating the same listview and putting different data in it.

So, can a viewpager be used by re-using the same single fragment? Or do I HAVE TO use multiple fragments?

I want the best performance, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple fragments tats the way . And moreover fragments 'll not take tat much size like activity. So go ahead dude.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class TitleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private String titles[] = new String[]{"View1","View2","View3"};
    private Fragment frags; 

    public TitleAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        frags = new FragmentView1();

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position){
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", titles[position]);
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
        frags.onPositionChange(position);
        return frags;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

}
```

I am not sure if returning the same fragment will through an exception or not. So let me know what happens.

Comment: Assuming that this works, wouldn't this just show the same thing in all the tabs? I do need to change what text get added to the listview. How could I do that in the fragmentactivity?

Comment: create a function in your fragment class onPositionChange and make changes in that function

Comment: look at my getItem function